# How do I access the three ints that determine the Color class' color?

Tags: java, colors

I need to make a method that takes no parameters that dims the Color, it is at the bottom of this code. It dims the values of the ints by 20%. I don't know how to access the ints made in those Color classes.
I put the placeholders 'a' 'b' and 'c' in place of what is supposed to access the three numbers that determine a Color's color.

```
public class Color {
final static Color RED = new Color(255, 0 , 0);
final static Color BLACK = new Color(0, 0 , 0);
final static Color GREEN = new Color(0, 255 , 0);
final static Color YELLOW = new Color(255, 255 , 0);
final static Color BLUE = new Color(0, 0 , 255);
final static Color MAGENTA = new Color(202, 31 , 123);
final static Color CYAN = new Color(0, 183 , 235);
final static Color WHITE = new Color(255, 255 , 255);

private int red;
private int green;
private int blue;

public Color(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a < 0) {
        a = 0;
    }
    if (b < 0) {
        b = 0;
    }
    if (c < 0) {
        c = 0;
    }
    if (a > 255) {
        a = 255;
    }
    if (b > 255) {
        b = 255;
    }
    if (c > 255) {
        c = 255;
    }
    Color custom = new Color(a, b, c);
}


public Color dim() {
    int newA = a * 0.80;
    int newB = b * 0.80;
    int newC = c * 0.80;
    Color newColor = (newA, newB, newC);
    return newColor;
}
```

It probably has to be this.Color(0) or something

Also how do I fix this boolean method that checks if two colors are the same, 'a' has to be replaced.

```
public boolean equals(Color) {
    if (Color a = Color b){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't your think that this will be recursive `Color custom = new Color(a, b, c);`

Comment: Can you explain your problem better? ie. Which line you are facing issues with?

Comment: You never assign the red, green, blue values to their properties (ie `this.red = a`)

Comment: Idk why that would be recursive

Comment: @SkiMaskTheSlumpGod `Color` calls `Color`, which calls `Color` which ... well, you get the idea

Comment: What should it call?

Answer (score 2):

You never assign the parameters to the objects properties, for example...

```
public Color(int a, int b, int c) {
    red = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, a));
    green = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, b));
    blue = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, c));
}
```

`dim` would the need to become...

```
public Color dim() {
    int newA = (int)(red * 0.80);
    int newB = (int)(green * 0.80);
    int newC = (int)(blue * 0.80);
    Color newColor = new Color(newA, newB, newC);
    return newColor;
}
```

because you want to modify the properties the object

> Also how do I fix this boolean method that checks if two colors are the same, 'a' has to be replaced.

This looks like a learning exercise to me and something your should take some time to figure out, but essentially, you need to determine if the "other" class is a "instance of" `Color` and if it is, if the properties (`red`, `green`, `blue`) are equal

Comment: The amazing thing is I have written an answer that looks almost exactly like this (including the `Math.min` and `Math.max` chain, and without seeing your answer). You missed `new Color` at `Color newColor = new Color(newA, newB, newC);` and you forgot to cast with with assignment to `newA`-`newC`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah, it's amazing how many times I use min(max) to constraint a range  - thinks for noting the things I was missing

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  too much Swift 

Comment: if (this.red == Color.red && this.green == Color.green && this.blue == Color.blue) { ?

Comment: @SkiMaskTheSlumpGod No, not really.  Ok, `Object` defines `equals` as `public void equals(Object other)`, so, assuming you're wanting to override this method, you need to test if the instance of the object you've passed to `equals` is actually a `Color` object.  However, if you are just making a new method `public void equals(Color color)`, then you're on the right track